# Having problems switching over to mySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to do a simple HTML form that sends data to DB:

Form:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input  type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input  type="text" />

    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the SQL to send the data on processor.php:

```
 //Connecting to sql db.
 $connect = mysqli_connect("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXX");
 //Sending form data to sql db.
 mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES    ('$_POST['name']','$_POST['age']', '$_POST['phone']', '$_POST['email']')";
 mysqli_close($connect);
```

I don't get error messages it just takes me to a blank page and no records are inserted into database.

Comment: I've rolled your update back, so it's still showing the original question. Your edit meant that the provided answer made no sense at all. If you're still having a problem, you'll get a much better response if you can add a new question with all the details in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input for age lacks a **name** .

```
<div class="field-box">
       <label>Age:</label>
       <input  type="text" name="age" /> 
</div>
```

And also do not insert directly a `$_POST` data. It would be best if you use **mysqli_real_escape_string** for added security. Your insert query as well lacks a closing **parenthesis**

```
//Connecting to sql db.
 $connect = mysqli_connect("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXX");
 //Sending form data to sql db.

$name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
$age   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['age']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['phone']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);


 mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES    ('$name', '$age', '$phone', '$email')");
```

Comment: Maybe, but that's not the major issue here.

Comment: @John Robertson your mysqli_real_escape_string not going to work. Please check the php manual for the same.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given. I got this error message on all the lines where I set the values from the HTML form.

Comment: @MattMcLaren see my edit mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']); I have added the db connection

Comment: I just uploaded the new code, per your instructions. I'm having problems with age being sent to DB and for some reason phone is being sent to email field in DB.

Answer (score 0):

There seems a problem with your query: A modified one looks like

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['age']."', '".$_POST['phone']."', '".$_POST['email']."')";
```

Directly inserting values without validations is not a good practice.

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before your entries towards database